# How does firestore's optimistic locking in transactions handle concurrent updates that cause a violation of a security rule?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

[Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention) does not seem to specify when or how security rules are evaluated in a transaction and how that interacts with retries and optimistic locking.

My use case is straightforward, I have a `lastUpdatedAt` field on my documents and I'm using a transaction to ensure that I grab the latest document and check that the `lastUpdatedAt` field so I can resolve any conflicts before issuing an update.

In pseudocode the pattern is this

```js
async function saveDocument(data: MyType, docRef: DocumentReference)
    await firebase.firestore().runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
        const latestDocRef = await transaction.get(docRef)
        const latestDoc = latestDocRef.data()

        if(latestDoc.lastUpdatedAt > data.lastUpdatedAt){
            data = resolveConflicts(data, latestDoc)
            data.lastUpdatedAt = latestDoc.lastUpdatedAt
        } 

        await transaction.update(docRef, data)
    }
}
```

Then in security rules I check to ensure that only updates with the latest or later lastUpdatedAt are allowed

```
 function hasNoLastUpdatedAtConflict(){
      return (!("lastUpdatedAt" in resource.data) || 
      resource.data.lastUpdatedAt == null ||
      request.resource.data.lastUpdatedAt >= resource.data.lastUpdatedAt);
 }

//in individualRules
  allow update: if  hasNoLastUpdatedAtConflict() && someOtherConditionsEtc();
```

The docs say

> In the Mobile/Web SDKs, a transaction keeps track of all the documents you read inside the transaction. The transaction completes its write operations only if none of those documents changed during the transaction's execution. If any document did change, the transaction handler retries the transaction. If the transaction can't get a clean result after a few retries, the transaction fails due to data contention.

However they don't specify how that behavior interacts with security rules. My transaction above is failing *somtimes* with a security rule violation. It only fails on a live Firestore environment, I haven't been able to make it fail in the emulator. I *suspect* what's happening is:

1. Transaction starts, sends doc to client
2. A concurrent write happens which changes lastUpdatedAt
3. The client does not see the new write so it can't resolve the conflict and it issues the update as-is
4. The security rule now fails because of the concurrent write when it would have otherwise succeeded
5. Firestore fails the whole transaction with permission-denied instead of retrying due to dirty data

I suppose I could implement client side retry in the case a transaction is rejected by a security rule violation but it's very surprising behavior if this is indeed what is happening.

Does anybody have insight into the actual behavior of security rules and Firestore transactions with optimistic locking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough testing I have confirmed that a firestore transaction using optimistic locking from the iOS/android library can be rejected with a permission-denied error due to a concurrent write happening after a document was read in the transaction.

The following scenario happens:

1. Begin transaction
2. Read a doc such as `{id: 1, lastUpdatedAt: 1, data: "foo"}`
3. Before writing to that doc in the transaction a cloud firestore trigger updates the doc to `{id: 1, lastUpdatedAt: 2, data: "foo"}`
4. Update doc in transaction `.update({lastUpdatedAt: 1, data: "bar"})`
5. Transaction throws exception `firestore/permission-denied` because this update violates a security rule of `request.resource.data.lastUpdatedAt >= resource.data.lastUpdatedAt`

The transaction does *not* get retried as the docs suggest, even though it performed a read of stale data. This means that users of the firestore libraries cannot rely on transactions being retried if it is possible that a concurrent write could cause the transaction to violate a security rule.

This is surprising and undocumented behavior!

Answer (score -1):

As per the [documentation and code sample](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#data_validation_for_atomic_operations), you can ensure that related documents are always updated atomically and always as part of a transaction or batch write using the [getAfter()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.getAfter) security rule function. It can be used to access and validate the state of a document after a set of operations completes but before Cloud Firestore commits the operations. Like get(), the getAfter() function takes a fully specified document path. You can use getAfter() to define sets of writes that must take place together as a transaction or batch.

These are some [access call limits](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-conditions#access_call_limits), which you may want to have a look at.

The documentation suggests that getAfter is useful to examine the contents of the database after the entire transaction's state would be recorded (in a sort of "staging" environment in memory), but before the transaction actually changes the database, visible to everyone. This is different from get(), because get() only looks at the actual contents of the database, before the transaction is finally committed. In short, getAfter() uses the entire staged write of the entire transaction or batch, while get uses the actual existing contents of the database.

getAfter() is useful when you need to examine other documents that may have been changed in the transaction or batch, and still have a chance to reject the entire transaction or batch by failing the rule. So, for example, if two documents being written in a single transaction must have some field value in common in order to be consistent, you need to use getAfter() to verify the equality between the two.

**Point of note** : The security rules for writes kick in before anything in the database has been changed by that write. That's how the security rules are able to safely and efficiently reject access, without having to roll back any writes that already happened.

Comment: I am aware of `getAfter` but it's not relevant to this situation. I'm only operating on a single document. The issue is that if a security rule gets violated due to a transaction reading stale data then the transaction does _not_ get retried and instead throws `permission-denied`.