# Lock Failing During Transaction Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, python-asyncio

The goal of my pick_doc function is to apply a lock to a Firestore document.

My python program will be deployed to cloud functions, and it's very important that no 2 functions lock/use the same document in their execution.

I am trying to use a Firestore Async Client to perform a transaction to achieve this locking mechanism. Between the read of the document, and the write to change the lock from False to True, multiple other functions are also applying the lock to the same document.

In my function, I am pulling 10 docs from firestore, picking 1, and want to only apply the lock to that 1 doc I selected.

I tried to implement a solution using a firestore async transaction, but documents that are changed between read and write by another firestore client are still being allowed to update.

I basically want a transaction to be rejected if the lock field has been changed by other Firestore clients.

```
class FirestoreClient:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
            cls._instance._client = None
        return cls._instance

    async def init_client(self, cred_file):
        try:
            self._client = AsyncClient.from_service_account_json(cred_file)
            print(self._client)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error initializing Firestore client: {e}")

    async def get_client(self):
        if self._client is None:
            raise ValueError("Firestore client not initialized")
        return self._client

    async def close_client(self):
        if self._client is not None:
            print(self._client)
            self._client.close()
            self._client = None
            print("Closed client")


    @firestore.async_transactional
    async def get_doc_lock(transaction, self):
        client = await self.get_client()

        docs_ref = client.collection('docs').where('doc_lock', '==', False)
        docs = await docs_ref.limit(10).get(transaction=transaction)

        if len(docs) == 0:
            return None

        #... logic for filtering the 10 docs goes here

        if len(docs) == 0:
            return None
        
        # pick a random doc from the filtered list
        doc = random.choice(docs)
        doc_ref = client.collection('docs').document(doc.id)
        dock_lock_update = {"doc_lock": True}
        transaction.update(doc_ref, dock_lock_update)
        return doc

    async def pick_doc(self):
        client = await self.get_client()
        tries = 0
        while True:
            tries += 1
            transaction = client.transaction()
            doc = await self.get_doc_lock(transaction, self)
            if doc is not None:
                break
            if tries > 10:
                return None
            else:
                await asyncio.sleep(tries * 3)
                print(f"Doc is None, trying again. Try number: {tries}")
                continue
        return doc
```

How can I cause the transaction to fail if the document has been changed between read and write?

Comment: If you are ok with adding extra field into your firestore document then you can use `optimistic concurrency control(OCC)` to solve this issue with adding a security rule with them take a look this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71187481/20239914)

Comment: Hi does my posted comment solve your issue ? If so I will post as an answer so that community members will also get the answer.