# How to solve memory limit in cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have issue with firebase functions and I am not sure how to proceed.

On few firebase functions that are used the most, I am getting the following memory limit error on every ~1000-2000 requests.

```
Memory limit of 512 MiB exceeded with 512 MiB used.
```

I guess I have some small memory leak, that after serving that amount of requests is enough to break it.

My main issue is that sometimes error is thrown and instance is killed inside firestore transaction, which causes firestore document to be locked for next few minutes. So I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to workaround memory limit issue by maybe killing instance after serving e.g. 500 requests, so new calls will go to the new instance?
2. How could I unlock document if transaction breaks, or could I maybe set a lock limit duration on document?

Thanks for help!

Comment: If the issue occur after several requests, and again and again, it's because you have a memory leak in your code. Start by fixing your code.

Comment: As suggested in the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#data_contention_in_the_mobileweb_sdks) You can add one extra field in your document as version and update version filed every time when you update other fields and Add firestore security rules for the same like `request.resource.data.version >= resource.data.version` as stated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71003613).